# Possible to Hide Script inside Base64 Image

Tags: javascript, html, image, security, base64

I know it's possible to encode images as base64 strings and render those images in html but I'm wondering if it's possible to do this with raw base64 string. The source of my base64 string isn't trusted, so I'm wondering if it's possible for this to be exploited as an entry for a cross site scripting attack.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that depending on a number of factors, it probably is possible.

I was able to find [one example](https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/tree/master/XSS%20injection#xss-in-files) using XSS in CSS:

```
div  {
    background-image: url("data:image/jpg;base64,<\/style><svg/onload=alert(document.domain)>");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

I'm sure other examples exist too, though it clearly all depends on how/where you're using that Base64 string.

The fact that you're using any input string from an untrusted source should be the more concerning thing in your case.

Comment: Great example - thanks! And yea, we'll definitely be running sanitation checks against it